# Xpath to match specific text

Tags: xpath

I have this HTML structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD3EM.jpg

```
<tbody>
                      <tr data-drupal-selector="edit-strings-996" class="odd">
                      <td><div id="edit-strings-996-original" class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-item form-type-item js-form-item-strings-996-original form-item-strings-996-original form-no-label">
      <label for="edit-strings-996-original" class="visually-hidden">Source string (Built-in English)</label>
        Search
        </div>
</span></td>
                      <td><div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-textarea form-type-textarea js-form-item-strings-996-translations-0 form-item-strings-996-translations-0 form-no-label">
      <label for="edit-strings-996-translations-0" class="visually-hidden">Translated string (Español)</label>
        <div class="form-textarea-wrapper">
  <textarea lang="es" data-drupal-selector="edit-strings-996-translations-0" id="edit-strings-996-translations-0" name="strings[996][translations][0]" rows="1" cols="60" class="form-textarea resize-vertical">Search</textarea>
</div>

        </div>
</td>
                  </tr>
                      <tr data-drupal-selector="edit-strings-1176" class="even">
                      <td><div id="edit-strings-1176-original" class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-item form-type-item js-form-item-strings-1176-original form-item-strings-1176-original form-no-label">
      <label for="edit-strings-1176-original" class="visually-hidden">Source string (Built-in English)</label>
        Search page
        </div>
```

I need a Xpath that I can find only the exact text "Search". I cannot use `contains()` because it will return all rows with this word, I need only the row with "Search" word only.
My knowledge of Xpath is not great, so I tried many things like:

```
//tbody/tr/td/div[.='Search']
//tbody/tr/td/div[normalize-space(.)='Search']
```

`//tbody/tr[1]/td/div/.` -> This one works but I cannot pass the `tr[1]` because I'll use this xpath in an automation and the text I want is not always in the first row, so I need to find by Text and not by Index.

The problem is that all texts have these whitespaces and it makes it worse for me to make it work.

Comment: Can you please remove the linked image and instead paste the actual relevant xml?

Comment: @StuartLC I added the source but I don't know how to format it correctly, I just copied the source page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text content of target `div` node is not just `"Search"`, but `"Source string ... Search"`, so you can try

```
//div[normalize-space(text()[2])='Search']
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't express myself correctly. I need an Xpath to only find the row with text "Search" only. I cannot use contains because it will return more than 30 results, I just need the one with exact text "Search"

Comment: Yep. It wasn't reflected on provided image, but now I see. The second XPath should work for this case

Comment: It does not work because all the texts have whitespaces as I mentioned in the question, so with `//div[text()='Search']` it does not find anything

Comment: Does this one `//div[normalize-space(text()[2])='Search']` works?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for the `div` which has text containing the string `Search`, this should work:

```
 //tbody/tr/td/div[contains(., 'Search')]
```

It's a bit dirty in that it would also detect `Search` anywhere under the `div`, e.g. including in the `label's` text, if applicable.

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't express myself correctly. I need an Xpath to only find the row with text "Search" only. I cannot use contains because it will return more than 30 results, I just need the one with exact text "Search"

Comment: Ok, looks like you have a workaround already. I'm not sure how much control you have over the HTML in Drupal, but if you can, would suggest that yourself / developers assign unique `id` attributes to your `div` elements, which will make identification of elements much less messy (and more performant). At a guess, this is for a Selenium selector, in which case performance probably doesn't matter that much?